# d3 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number date

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I've found a half dozen posts regarding this error but none seem to resolve my issue.

The data as it comes from firebase:

```
data = [{percent:24,year:1790},....]

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse; 
// so I want to convert the year to a 'date' for d3 time scale
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.year = parseDate(d.year.toString());
  d.percent = +d.percent;
});
```

which then the data looks like

```
console.log(data);
[{percent:24,year:Fri Jan 01 1790 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)}...]
```

my x scale

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, this.width]);
```

my x domain

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.year; }));
```

my line

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.percent); });
```

then my chart (there is a base chart that this is extending)

```
this.chart.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
```

Which when added has the exception ...

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number,
```

**UPDATE**

So here is the working code using sample data the code is more or less a copy paste from d3 example site using a csv instead of tsv

**This works fine**

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y");

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("./data/debt-public-percent-gdp.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

function type(d) {
  d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}
```

**This does not work** 
Using the same datasource here is my 'Base Chart'

```
export class BaseChart{
   constructor(data,elem,config = {}){
      var d3 = require('d3');
      this.data = data;
      this.svg = d3.select('#'+elem).append('svg');
      this.margin = {
         left: 30,
         top: 30,
         right: 30,
         bottom: 30,
      };

      let width = config.width ? config.width : 600;
      let height = config.height ? config.height : 300;
      this.svg.attr('height', height);
      this.svg.attr('width', width);

      this.width = width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
      this.height = height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
      this.chart = this.svg.append('g')
         .attr('width', this.width)
         .attr('height', this.height)
         .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left},${this.margin.top})`);

   }
}
```

Chart that Extends the Base Chart

```
export class FedDebtPercentGDP extends BaseChart{
  constructor(data, elem, config){
    super(data, elem, config);

         var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, this.width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([this.height, 0]);
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

  this.chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
  //
  this.chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  this.chart.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

  }
}
```

The code that calls the chart

```
d3.csv('./data/debt-public-percent-gdp.csv', type, function(error, data) {
   new FedDebtPercentGDP(data, "debt-to-gdp", {width: '100%'});
});
```

The data

```
date,close
1790,30
1791,29
1792,28
1793,24
1794,22
1795,19
1796,16
1797,17
1798,16
1799,16
1800,15
1801,13
1802,14
1803,14
1804,13
1805,11
1806,10
1807,10
1808,9
1809,7
1810,6
1811,6
1812,7
1813,8
1814,9
1815,10
1816,10
1817,8
1818,7
1819,7
1820,8
1821,9
1822,8
1823,8
1824,8
1825,7
1826,6
1827,6
1828,5
1829,4
1830,3
1831,2
1832,1
1833,0
1834,0
1835,0
1836,0
1837,0
1838,1
1839,0
1840,0
1841,1
1842,1
1843,2
1844,1
1845,1
1846,1
1847,2
1848,2
1849,3
1850,2
...
```

Comment: Everything seems to be Ok to me, can you please fiddle the full code.

Comment: I updated to include full sample

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with the code that you've provided. I guess you did not paste it all. The excerpt you pasted definitely does not have `this.chart` defined, for example, so it is not possible to reconstruct your error message.

That being said, it is still possible to identify the main problem:

The error message says it all: as you have parsed `d.year` and turned it into a string, but the path needs a number as an argument there is a 'type mismatch'-kind of error in your code.

You can see how your data looks like in the console log that you've provided. `year` is turned into a string.

I would recommend leaving `d.year` as it is, and if you really need, you can create a new attribute called for example `date` if you need the date in that format. So if it is needed for displaying the date, you can use that one, while `year` can be used for path calculation in its original format.